# How to export JIRA report with filter using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, curl, jira, jira-rest-api

In short, I need to export a JIRA report through a PowerShell script.

I've had better luck through an interactive console, but nothing I try seems to work through a PowerShell script. Note that I know nothing about the REST API and am wondering if there's a better solution there.

I'm trying to use curl (inside PowerShell) and have the following:

```
$url = "http://jiraServer/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/16403/SearchRequest-16403.xls?tempMax=100"
curl.exe $url -o C:\reports\report.xls
```

I've tried several variations of this and, when ran in PowerShell, I get one of the following:

1) An HTML output file of a JIRA page wanting to log in

2) A fairly ambiguous PowerShell error
Here's an example of the error I sometimes get:

```
curl.exe :  % Total   % Received % xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
At C:\scripts\psScript.ps1:69 char:3
+ & $curlLocation $url -o C:\reports\report.xls
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: ( % Total % ... Time Current:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: Did you know JIRA has a powershell module? https://github.com/AtlassianPS/JiraPS

Comment: I did not know, but unfortunately I'm in an environment where we cannot download to our network at this time. Still, this may help someone else so thank you for the input.

Comment: [Here's their documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/).  I'd suggest [looking at `Invoke-Restmethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-5.1)